Underscores in headers AWS API Gateway
I have created an API Gateway using Sam cli. Within the request, I am sending a header named access_token, which the API Gateway removes from the request. It only allows sending the header without an underscore like this: access-token
This is the request:

curl --location 'https://localhost:3000/api/testEdpoint' 
--header 'access_token: theaccesstoken'

The problem is that I cannot access the client's request to change from access_token to access-token. Is there any workaround or option where I can tell the Gateway to accept underscore in the headers and not remove them from the request?
